# autodesk forge viewer.js update from 6.5.1 to 6.6 or 7.1, 2d hyperlink promise exception

Tags: autodesk-forge

change view from 3d to 2d view.
In 6.5.1 
 viewer.load(document.getViewablePath(Views2D));
 no exception
In 6.6
 viewer.load(document.getViewablePath(Views2D)); 
//promise exception in chrome console
In 7.1
 viewer.loadModel(document.getViewablePath(Views2D), {});
//promise exception in chrome console

```
    Uncaught (in promise) 
    {instanceTree: null, maxTreeDepth: 0, err: undefined}
    Promise.then (async)        
    loadHyperlinks  @   HyperlinkTool.js:323
    activate    @   HyperlinkTool.js:123
    activateTool    @   ToolController.js:265
    f.load  @   Hyperlink.js:42
    loadExtensionLocal  @   ExtensionManager.js:270
    loadExtension   @   ExtensionManager.js:213
    (anonymous) @   ExtensionManager.js:312
    o.onload    @   globals.js:183
    load (async)        
    u   @   globals.js:185
    (anonymous) @   ExtensionManager.js:310
    loadExtensionAsync  @   ExtensionManager.js:309
    loadExtension   @   ExtensionManager.js:205
    (anonymous) @   GuiViewer3D.js:412
    setTimeout (async)      
    D.createUI  @   GuiViewer3D.js:406
    (anonymous) @   GuiViewer3D.js:300
    (anonymous) @   GuiViewer3D.js:288
    setTimeout (async)      
    (anonymous) @   GuiViewer3D.js:316
    (anonymous) @   Viewer3D.js:1228
    (anonymous) @   F2DLoader.js:420
```

Comment: This is a known issue and our Engineering is investigating - will let you know once they have updates

Answer (score 0):

Engineering is still taking time to address this issue.

While we wait for their fix we can work around this issue by disabling the `hyperlink` extension in our load options:

```
new Autodesk.Viewing.Private.GuiViewer3D(...),{disabledExtensions:{hyperlink:true}}
```